# Sailpoint IdentityNow Customization

Tags: identity-management, sailpoint

I wonder if any of you know if it is possible to do IDN Customization and to what extent.
I want to add new UI pages, and new widgets, make forms available, and more.
If you have any idea on how to do those, much appreciated!

p.s. I have conducted research but the documentation available points to it not being possible although it is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The whole idea of a cloud service is that it is standardized and not (really) customizable. Instead, it is *configurable*. IdentityNow provides some flexibility using workflows and forms that can be used in workflows. Adding new pages or widgets is not possible. At least not yet. You can submit an idea with SailPoint, though.

Other than that, one can extract information from IdentityNow using the public API endpoints, for use in external systems.